# in R ts package with multiple attributes in time series

Tags: r

R supports

```
pol_pos = ts(p$POS, frequency = 12, start = c(2017,8))
```

but I need to use multiple attributes of the data, like

```
pol_pos = ts( p$POS, p$NEG, frequency = 12, start = c(2017,8))
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  The first parameter needs to be a multi-column object:

```
pol_pos=ts(p[, c("POS", "NEG")], frequency = 12, start = c(2017,8))
```

Comment: @arun You are most welcome.  If you find this answer useful, please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark directly beneath the score of my answer.